# How to get window/global in the following Jest test?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

This is the class I'm working with:

```
class VRMaker extends Aframe {
  constructor () {
    super(...arguments)
  }
}

window.VRMaker = new VRMaker()
export default VRMaker
```

I use it like this:

```
import './src'

window.onload = function () {
  VRMaker.generateAframe()
  console.log(VRMaker.getCurrentPanorama())
}
```

However when I try to access VRMaker in a Jest file:

```
import '../src'

test('first test', () => {
  let result
  window.onload = function () {
    console.log(VRMaker)
    result = VRMaker
    expect(result).toEqual({})
  }
})
```

I get this error:

```
  MethodMissingError: __call, use method '__call(method, args)' in your class to catch.

> 44 |   console.log(VRMaker)
  45 |   result = VRMaker
  46 |   expect(result).toEqual({})
  47 | })

  at Object.get (node_modules/method-missing/lib/proxy.js:38:13)
  at Object.<anonymous>.test (test/helpers.test.js:44:11)
```

Why is this and how to fix it? (I tried replacing `window` with `global` but I get the same error.)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is probably `window.onload` which is just a reference. During initial compilation of JS window.onload gets assigned to the last reference point. 
You should probably put your source code as IFFE

```
import './src'

(function () {
  VRMaker.generateAframe()
  console.log(VRMaker.getCurrentPanorama())
})();
```

See if that works out.

Comment: So the IFFE should be inside `window.onload`? Inside `test(`?

Comment: Main src file. Actually window.onload based programming is wrong IMO. You should rather import/export and consume that in test and test against it.

Comment: So that IFFE should be placed in the Jest test file right? But in which part? Since the `src/index.js` file is a Class declaration.

Comment: try in jest file `import VRMaker from '../src'` and then test against that

Answer (score 1):

There is no `window` and no `window.onload` in jest. If you have a module that you want to test than just import it and work directly on it

```
import VRMaker from './src'

describe('VRMaker', ()=>{
  it('does something', ()=>{
   frame = new VRMaker()
  })
})
```

and if you want to test that it was added to the window object

```
import VRMaker from './src'

describe('VRMaker', ()=>{
  it('does something', ()=>{
   expect(global. VRMaker).toBeDefined()
  })
})
```